# Where is dataset uuid generated by pyCSW harvest?

Tags: pycsw

When pyCSW harvests from e.g. a WMS service, it will create a database entry with a uuid.
I wonder, where this uuid comes from.

Is it generated by pyCSW on harvesting or is it inherent to the harvested dataset and only obtained by pyCSW?

If it is generated by pyCSW, how can datasets be updated (based on the same uuid) on subsequent harvesting of the same service?

I didn't find relevant information in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer myself by having a look into the source code and the logs.

From my understanding, when harvesting a WMS service, pyCSW will generate a new uuid. If a record for the service url exists, it will keep the old uuid for the updated entry.